# nose multiprocess problems

Tags: python, nose, multiprocess

I'm having a problem running nose tests.  When I run my suite from Eclipse, using `Run As>Python unit-test` with the test runner set to `Nose test runner` and arguments `--verbosity=2 --processes=2 --process-timeout=300` in the Eclipse preferences for `PyDev>PyUnit`, I get a nice, orderly run where 4 new python processes spin up, and I get results back for my 19 tests (a class derived from `object` with 2 test generator methods, the first dispatching 6 tests, the second 13) in a few minutes (the tests are each making a sequence of REST calls then doing some validation).  However, when I run the same file from the command line using `nosetests --processes=2 --verbosity=2 --process-timeout=300 testfile.py`, it spawns 100s of new Python processes that seem to be organized in groups, with one having a bit over 6k in memory usage and the others having 50-500k.  These processes keep spawning indefinitely, and the tests never complete, until I start manually killing the processes.  If I run the tests from the command line without multiprocessing, they complete just fine as well.

Is Eclipse doing some extra corralling of the test processes?  Could I potentially be running different versions of Nose in Eclipse and from the command line (even though I only see 1 nose install, in site-packages)?

Answer (score -1):

Try to play with:

```
_multiprocess_can_split_
and 
_multiprocess_shared_
```

in your test classes.

doc: http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc_tests/test_multiprocess/multiprocess.html